# Не биндятся данные на балун

Tags: yandex-maps-api, knockoutjs, yandexmapkit

Использую KnockoutJS и Яндекс Карты.

Данные на страницу биндятся, а в балун нет. Можно ли так биндить данные на яндекс карту? Если нет, то какое решение подскажите, может библиотека какая есть?

Пример:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Showing pixel and tile coordinates</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js'></script>
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function Note(id, title, content) {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
            this.content = content;
        }

        Note.LAYOUT = 'привет<br> <span data-bind="$root.hello"></span>' +
                '<table class="table table-hover">' +
                    '<thead>' +
                        '<tr>' +
                            '<th>#</th>' +
                            '<th>Заголовок</th>' +
                            '<th>Содержимое</th>' +
                        '</tr>' +
                    '</thead>' +
                    '<tbody>' +
                        '<tr data-bind="foreach: notes">' +
                            '<td data-bind="text: id"></td>' +
                            '<td data-bind="text: title"></td>' +
                            '<td data-bind="text: content"></td>' +
                        '</tr>' +
                    '</tbody>' +
                '</table>';

        function NoteViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.hello = ko.observable('пока');
            self.notes = ko.observableArray([
                new Note(0, 'Первая заметка', 'Тут много текста'),
                new Note(1, 'Вторая заметка', 'Тут много другого текста')
            ]);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Заголовок</th>
                <th>Содержимое</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: notes">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: title"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: content"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        ymaps.ready(init);
        var myMap,
            myPlacemark;

        function init() {
            myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
                center: [55.76, 37.64],
                zoom: 7
            });

            myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.76, 37.64], {
                hintContent: 'Москва!',
                balloonContent: Note.LAYOUT
            });

            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

            ko.applyBindings(new NoteViewModel());
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myPlacemark.events.add('balloonopen', function (args) {
    // TODO reapply knockout bindings
});
```